# C/C++: Is this a 2D array? Why parentheses in array is syntactically correct?

Tags: c++, arrays, comma-operator

I am just starting to learn C++ and saw the following code sample.
The code declared an integer array with paratheses and can compile without a syntax error. Is this a 2D array declation?

```
int array[] = {(10, 9), (8, 7), (6, 5), (4, 3), (2, 1),(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)};
```

Thank you!

Comment: `(10, 9)` is `9` with comma operator.

Comment: Examine the contents of the array with debugger or `cout`. Also look up the comma operator.

Comment: array[i] will have the 2nd value of i^th bracket.

Comment: May we know where you found this "C++" course so we can burn it to the ground?

Comment: *and saw the following code sample* -- In what context did you find this code sample?  Was it a "weird things to do in C++", sample?  A beginner C++ book, even an advanced book, wouldn't have an example code like this, front and center.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not a 2D array but a 1D array.

*A comma operator* is used in `(10, 9)` and things like this. This operator first evaluate the lefthand operand, then discard the result and evaluate the righthand operand. The evaluation result of a comma operator is the evaluation result of the rightnand operand.

Therefore, the declaration means

```
int array[] = {9, 7, 5, 3, 1,2, 4, 6, 8, 10};
```

Note that the commas to separate between elements aren't comma operators.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have a 2D array, you may write as follows:

```
int array[][2] = {{10, 9}, {8, 7}, {6, 5}, {4, 3}, {2, 1},{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}};
cout << "Size: " << sizeof(array) << endl;
for (int i=0; i<sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]); i++)
    cout << array[i][0] << ',' << array[i][1] << endl;
```

Answer (score -2):

2d array looks something like this:

```
type name[size1][size2] = {e1,e1,...}
```

example:

```
int a[3][4] = {  
   {0, 1, 2, 3} ,   /*  initializers for row indexed by 0 */
   {4, 5, 6, 7} ,   /*  initializers for row indexed by 1 */
   {8, 9, 10, 11}   /*  initializers for row indexed by 2 */
};
```

yours is just a simple array..
there are plenty examples on internet just google.

Answer (score -2):

No.  It is a 1-dimensional array.  The statement simply declare an integer array with 10 integers, but the parentheses inside the braces are really a myth.

If you want a 2-dimensional array, it may be declared as

```
int array[][2]
```